# how can I run my script automatically on ac switching

Tags: 11.04, laptop, power-management, battery

So, I wan't to run it when start work on AC and this or better other script when  start work from battery

I tried

- /etc/acpi/power.sh
- adding symlink to /etc/laptop-mode/battery-start

It seems to not working

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? What didn't work? How did you observe it?

Comment: @user unknown Oh I was wrong. I tried 1 > /testfile but  i forgot "echo". SHould I delete question?

Comment: Don't delete it, but tell us in an answer, which of the both methods above worked, and how you found out. If this is the best answer, you can even accept it.

Comment: Make sure that laptop-mode is actually running..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want with a script in `/etc/pm/power.d`.  Quoting from the `HOWTO.hooks` file in `pm-utils`:

> How to write a pm-utils hook:
>
> PARAMETERS
>
> A pm-utils hook is simply an executable file that accepts at least one 
>   parameter.
>
> For hooks in power.d, the potential values of that parameter are:
>
> - true -- the hook MUST perform whatever action is appropriate when the system 
>         transitions TO battery power.
> - false -- The hook MUST perform whatever action is appropriate when the system
>         transitions FROM battery power.

You might also want to read some of the existing power hooks in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d` for ideas about how to structure your script.

Note that if you use the `pm-utils` interface, you'll be told whether you're on AC power or not through the first argument: if `$1` is `true`, then you're switching to battery power, and if it is `false` then you're switching back to mains power.

Answer (score 2):

I achieve the similar goal by using acpi.

use /usr/bin/acpi_listen to catch the acpi event you want, on my lapttop, the event that fire when switch to battery is "ac_adapter ACPI0003:00 00000080 00000000".
so I create a new event : /etc/acpi/events/switch-to-battery, below is the content:

```
event=ac_adapter ACPI0003:00 00000080 00000000
action=/etc/acpi/switch-to-battery.sh
```

Just do whatever you want in ac_adapter.sh. More examples can be found if acpi-support is installed.

Last, execute this command to make the new event to take effect.

```
sudo service acpid restart
```

Comment: I found this is the only way to do that in 16.04 because `/etc/pm` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really correct question.
I get some error, but now I correct and my power.sh  and it works

```
if on_ac_power; then
  echo 0 > /home/riad/1 
  #on ac
else 
  echo 1 > /home/riad/1
  #on battery
fi
```

and it works

Comment: Note that if you use the `pm-utils` interface I described in my answer, you'll be told whether you're on AC power or not through the first argument: if `$1` is `true`, then you're switching to battery power, and if it is `false` then you're switching back to mains power.