# run script when power mode changes

Tags: scripts, 15.10, power-management, brightness, battery

I wrote myself a bash script and when this script is called it changes my display brightness. Now i want to run this script when my ac-adapter is unplugged or the ac-adapter gets plugged in. Where can I add some events?

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/55904/how-can-i-run-my-script-automatically-on-ac-switching, but I don't have `/etc/pm/power.d` in 15.10, so I guess that wouldn't work.

Comment: See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/q/739617/295286  . Your question is not strictly duplicate of that, but my answer essentially achieves the same task.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to run this script when my ac-adapter is unplugged or the
>   ac-adapter gets plugged in

There's a couple of ways. I've written a [script](https://askubuntu.com/q/739617/295286) specifically for that purpose , which uses `on_ac_power` script that comes with Ubuntu by default. This method simply uses infinite while loop to constantly poll the return of `on_ac_power`. Starting this script is done using [Startup Applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/295286) app which launches commands when user logs into Gnome or Unity.

Another approach is via ACPI events. As shown on [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/acpid) , you can place a script into `/etc/acpi` folder that will perform checks for the presence of a specific AC adapter in `/sys/class/backlight` folder, and change a specific value in a file accordingly.